# Can Maven PMD plugin be used to check for Java and Javascript in one run?

Tags: java, maven, coding-style, pmd

Reading the documentation, I can't figure out how the [Maven PMD plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/index.html) can be configured to check for Java and Javascript violation in one run.

Because of our internal workflow, I would like to generate only one report with all errors to be published in Jenkins.

Did you succeed in checking for both languages at one?

Comment: Maybe you can merge reports with Sonar ?

Comment: It should do the job. But setting up a full Sonar, just for that is a bit heavy... That will be a good solution if we later move to Sonar. Thanks for the idea anyway :)

Comment: If you find another solution let me know, as I also have Java and JavaScript.